# Icinga 2 sends notifications outside of specified time period

Tags: monitoring, icinga, icinga2

I'm trying to send different notifications in different time periods, basically I want to send all notifications during work hours, but only notifications for hosts marked emergency during off hours.

```
apply Notification "mike-on" to Host {
  import "mail-host-notification"
  users = [ "sms" ]
  period = "mikehours"
  assign where host.vars.notification.mail
}

apply Notification "mike-off" to Host {
  import "mail-host-notification"
  users = [ "sms" ]
  period = "nonmikehours"
  assign where host.vars.emergency == true
}
```

sms is simply a contact with the email set to mynumber@carrier.net, and the time periods are defined as follows

```
object TimePeriod "mikehours" {
  import "legacy-timeperiod"

  display_name = "Mike's work hours"
  ranges = {
    "monday"    = "06:00-23:00"
    "tuesday"   = "06:00-23:00"
    "wednesday" = "06:00-23:00"
    "thursday"  = "06:00-23:00"
    "friday"    = "06:00-23:00"
    "saturday"  = "07:00-22:00"
    "sunday"    = "07:00-22:00"
  }
}

object TimePeriod "nonmikehours" {
  import "legacy-timeperiod"
  display_name = "Mike's off hours"
  ranges = {
    "monday"    = "00:00-06:00,23:00-24:00"
    "tuesday"   = "00:00-06:00,23:00-24:00"
    "wednesday" = "00:00-06:00,23:00-24:00"
    "thursday"  = "00:00-06:00,23:00-24:00"
    "friday"    = "00:00-06:00,23:00-24:00"
    "saturday"  = "00:00-07:00,22:00-24:00"
    "sunday"    = "00:00-07:00,22:00-24:00"
  }
}
```

However, I still receive all notifications via sms even outside of the specified work hours.

Answer (score 1):

Apply rules are evaluated on their own. If your assign/ignore where expressions match (as with "assign where host.vars.notification.mail" probably matching all hosts) they will generate a notification object. Verify that by 'object list' or the rest api endpoint /v1/objects/notifications.
The second apply rule only matches on your custom attribute being set, and adds an additional notification object. So your comment's solution is perfectly fine.

You can omit the "== true" comparison btw. Icinga 2 assumes that automatically for boolean attributes.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... I understand that it matched all hosts, but shouldn't period still prevent notifications from being sent outside of that time period?

Comment: Your initial configuration from the original post did create notification objects for *all* hosts which had "vars.notification.mail" defined. So you would have received sms notification for "mikehours" period no matter what else you define. The additional apply rule "emergency" adds *another* notification.

Comment: so then what does the period actually change? I understand I created a notification object for every host, and then another on the hosts with emergency defined, but shouldn't period define the period of time in which that notification is sent?

Comment: Your two notifications match the entire 24x7 period, one 6-23 on monday e.g. the other one from 0-6 and 23-24. That way you'll always receive notifications from two different periods. Re-think your notification strategy, take pen and paper and draw your config items and their matched patters.

Comment: I understand that there is always a notification for any given time, but during the night it should only be a notification for certain hosts.

Comment: Additionally, the solution I proposed does not seem to be working correctly, upon further inspection it is now sending notifications via text at all times of night

Comment: for anyone interested I found the issue in my proposed solution, a simple group assignment mistake that was sending the standard email notifications to the sms user as well

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution that works for me:

```
apply Notification "mike-on" to Host {
  import "mail-host-notification"

  users = [ "sms" ]

  period = "mikehours"

  assign where host.vars.notification.mail && !host.vars.emergency
}

apply Notification "emergency" to Host {
  import "mail-host-notification"
  users = [ "sms" ]
  period = "24x7"
  assign where host.vars.emergency == true
}
```

I'd still love an answer as to why my original solution failed, but this is a much better way to do it anyhow.